# Get array element by value in similar way like getting by $key

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Is there a possibility in PHP to get an array element by it's value. What I wan't to do is to update an element without knowing the key but nowing it's value:

```
 $translations = array(
     "en" => 123,
     "de" => 456,
     "es" => 789,
     "fr" => 901
 );
```

i know that what i wan't to do can be done with an foreach loop:

```
foreach($translations as $lang=>$id):
   if($id == 123) $translations[$lang] = 0;
endforeach;
```

But is there any possibility to avoid this loop and to automatically set it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
if(false!==($key = array_search(123, $translations)))
{
   $translations[$key] = 0;
}
```

-be aware that value can be non-unique, so `array_search()` will find only first key. If you need all of them, you'll have to either iterate through array with `foreach` or use something like [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this :

```
$translations[array_search('123',  $translations)] = 0;
```

Edit: use the solution proposed by Alma Do Mundo, he is right about checking the return value

Comment: Yes you are right, no point of editing my answer to match yours. I give you credits =)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way also.

Use array_keys function with search_values parameter. It will give you the array of keys which are having these values. Then you can update the original array based on the new array.

It will take care of all the duplicate values also.

```
$translations = array(
     "en" => 123,
     "de" => 456,
     "es" => 789,
     "fr" => 901,
     "it" => 123
 );

 $arr=array_keys($translations,$seach_value);

 if(count($arr)){
 foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $translations[$value]=$new_value;
 }
 }
```

Comment: i have added "it" => 123 to your source array for showing the demo for repeated values.